# What does the "Flush" item do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Flush is a six-charge item in Binding of Isaac: Rebirth. Its description is "???" and it comes standard in the High Brow challenge.

What does it do?

Answer (score 10):

It turns enemies on screen into poop. Does not work on bosses.

Before:
[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: To clarify: All non-boss enemies. Bosses are unaffected.

Comment: If you have the afterbirth DLC this item kills poop bosses when used.